# How to calculate the intersection point between an infinite line and a line segment?

Tags: math, geometry, glsl, shader, line-intersection

Basically, a function that fulfills this signature:

```
function getLineIntersection(vec2 p0, vec2 direction, vec2 p2, vec2 p3) {
   // return a vec2
}
```

I have looked around at existing solutions, and they all seem to deal with how to find the intersection between two line segments, or between two infinite lines. Is there a solution for this problem where the line has an initial position, an angle, and needs to determine if it intersects with a line segment? Basically, something like this:

[image]

There should be one line segment that starts in a location and has a unit direction, and another line segment that is just a line connected by two points. Is this possible, and if so, is there a good way of calculating the intersection point, if it exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've a endless line which is defined by a point `P` and a normalized direction `R` and a second endless line, which is defined by a point `Q` and a direction `S`, then the intersection point of the endless lines `X` is:

[image]

```non
alpha ... angle between Q-P and R
beta  ... angle between R and S

gamma  =  180° - alpha - beta

h  =  | Q - P | * sin(alpha)
u  =  h / sin(beta)

t  = | Q - P | * sin(gamma) / sin(beta)

t  =  dot(Q-P, (S.y, -S.x)) / dot(R, (S.y, -S.x))  =  determinant(mat2(Q-P, S)) / determinant(mat2(R, S))
u  =  dot(Q-P, (R.y, -R.x)) / dot(R, (S.y, -S.x))  =  determinant(mat2(Q-P, R)) / determinant(mat2(R, S))

X  =  P + R * t  =  Q + S * u
```

If you want to detect if the intersection is on the lien, you need to compare the distance of the intersection point with the length of the line.
The intersection point (`X`) is on the line segment if `t` is in [0.0, 1.0] for `X = p2 + (p3 - p2) * t`

```c
vec2 getLineIntersection(vec2 p0, vec2 direction, vec2 p2, vec2 p3) 
{
    vec2 P = p2;
    vec2 R = p3 - p2;  
    vec2 Q = p0;
    vec2 S = direction;

    vec2 N = vec2(S.y, -S.x);
    float t = dot(Q-P, N) / dot(R, N);

    if (t >= 0.0 && t <= 1.0)
        return P + R * t;

    return vec2(-1.0);
}
```

Comment: Does this work if only one of the lines is a segment and the other one is a line with a start point and a direction that extends infinitely? Based on the image it looks like it is for two infinite lines, but in my case I have a line segment and a line ray (with an initial point and a direction)

Comment: @RyanPeschel The image is just the explanation for the intersection point.

Comment: @RyanPeschel What should be returned by the function if the intersection is not on the segment?

Comment: Hmm, not sure. I'm writing this in GLSL so I don't think they have a concept of a null, so I'd probably just use some arbitrary negative point as a signal that the intersection was not found, because all my lines exist from [0, infinite] and none have any negative coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the intersection of two infinite lines, expressed in parametric form (e.g., A + tp, where A is the "start point", p is the direction vector and t is a scalar parameter). Solve a system of two equations to get the two parameters of the intersection point.

Now if one of your lines is really a segment AB, and B = A + p (i.e., the direction vector goes from A to B), then if the parameter t is between 0 and 1, the intersection lies on the segment.